# Выполнения php скрипта на фоне, а пользователю выводить только прогресс

Tags: php

Занялся созданием небольшого сервиса для сбора статистики с социальных сетей.

Интересует такой вопрос: как сделать, чтобы допустим цикл php который парсит нужную информацию, выполнялся на фоне, без перезагрузки страницы, а человек видел только прогресс в процентах?

Что нужно выучить для этого? В какую сторону вообще копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну для начала вам нужно изучить Ajax, эта технология нужна чтобы вы без перезагрузки страницы обращались к серверу, в принципе этого хватит чтобы показывать прогресс работы пользователю. Можно также изучить `poling` И его ралезацию на Ajax, ну и `ignore_user_abort()` это функция в PHP. Также прочитете про запуск программ через cronbat на сервере. Будет полезно.